# Late night taxis from Don Mueang airport?

Tags: airport-transfer, taxis, bangkok, dmk

I'm looking at flights from Tokyo to Bangkok, and one of the more convenient ones unfortunately arrives at Don Mueang Airport at 00:55. Will there be taxis at the taxi stand then?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  Taxis are available as long as flights are scheduled.

Comment: (+1) Tom is correct. Make sure you go to the public taxi stand inside the airport, which is in the *domestic* arrival area (turn left after leaving the international arrival area, and walk all the way). You get the form from them first, it will have the taxi number, and they'll call the driver for you (they can also write down the destination in Thai if you ask). You pay by meter plus extra 50 Baht airport surcharge.